# I am trying to PCB using a schematic I made

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, routing

[image][image][image][image]Routing isnt my strong point. I would like to know if this looks correct?

So I have 230V AC to 12V DC. I then have DC coupling, then an LED emitter, transimpedance amplifier, then active high pass filter, then a comparator abd finally a power transistor npn which will be connected to a 12V relay to turn a device of 230V.

[image]

Do the connections look fine? I want to distribute 12V power rail to each device so no voltage drop.

[image]

Comment: If there's 230V AC coming onto that board, you have some _big_ problems, and that 7812 is going to explode or something because that's a _massive_ overvoltage.

Comment: That 7812 won't last for more than a few milliseconds if the input is at 230Vac

Comment: No at the beginning there will be a 230V to 12V transformer

Comment: @M2T156 Okay, make sure you clarify that in your question. Anyway, in my opinion, your routing looks amateurish (which is to be expected since you claim it isn't your strong point). Since this circuit doesn't have any high voltages, high currents, or high frequencies, it will probably work, but this circuitry is very spread-out and your power traces are thin, there's no ground plane, and components seem to have been placed with little thought given to their function or how they impact routing of other traces. I don't have the time to write this up as a proper answer right now though.

Comment: You appear to be using SMD resistors, which is OK but why would you do that when nearly all other components are through-hole ones. Your traces are all very thin while there is **no reason** to have that. Especially the supply lines: make them as wide as possible. PCBs are made with a copper layer and excess copper is then removed. The less copper removed the better! I suggest to have a look at random PCBs designed by others, search the internet, look in some broken equipment just to see "how it's done". Example: https://groenholdt.net/tag_linear_regulator_index.html

Comment: Thank you hearth for your honest feedback. When you do have the time, I would really appreciate if you can go into a bit more detail. I will try and make a better version, grouping each part together, thickening the power routing and so on.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I will change the resistors and capacitors to through hole and thicken the lines.

Comment: @M2T156 For future reference, put an @ before someone's name and they'll get a notification about your message. I'm only seeing your messages because I'm manually checking this question (since you seem new, and new people often don't realize how the notifications work).

Comment: More examples: https://xtronic.org/circuit/circuit-regulated-power-supply-with-lm317/

Comment: The 12V transformer might produce as much as 20VDC when lightly loaded. Your 4700uF capacitor has no voltage rating but it looks rather small to be rated for (say) 25VDC. Maybe the silk screen circle does not represent the real diameter.

Comment: do you have flyback diode for the relay when its switched off?

Comment: Routing aside, I have some doubt this circuit will do what you want. For example, the bias of the non-inverting input of IC3 is outside the common mode range of the  741 (it's not a single supply op-amp). But that's not your question.

Comment: Hasan yes I do have one included

Comment: Spehro thank you for your feedback but I have a working prototype and it works flawlessly/

Comment: i suggest to make bottom layer as gnd plane all routing on top, and make your path without corners or bends (usually 45 deg).. make connectors instead of holes (i assume you will make solder wires later?).

Comment: By C2 / C10 you have two vias, they appear to be very small. Have you checked with your board house to see if they are a standard size?

Comment: Should I increase the size? I haven't checked if they have a standard size. I know it might sound stupid but is it really necessary to know?

Comment: Vcc- on your 741 (according to the data sheet I looked at) needs to be -5 to -15v. And your decoupling capacitors are missing / far away from the ICs.

Comment: There are a number of design failures to component specs. So fix those 1st. Vebo is exceeded on Astable with 12V design, so use a Schmitt Trigger Astable design (using CMOS SCh. Inverter) is better.  OA does not sense to 0V nor drive rail to rail. U1g needs a positive feedback ratio to exceed the % ripple to avoid relay chatter which might also be done with a CMOS Schmitt Inverter, and the Relay coil needs a reversed diode to clamp turnoff LdI/dt=V

Comment: Would you please give me a new sketch of a perfect design please so I can learn from it?

Comment: Add ground plane to both sides, and delete the ground path snaking its way around the board.  Connect the two sides via Vias.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Mixing SMD and THR can mean cheaper series manufacturing than pure THR. I have a real world example where we made a board with mixed SMD/THR to save money. Then some know-it-all came and told us that it will be better to use THR all the way. So we changed the design. Then all assembly companies charged much more for the work, since it now took them more time to rig everything. So we changed back again. Lesson learnt: there is no universal rule. This is all about what kind of equipment the assembly company got and your production volumes.

Comment: It is also preferred to drop tantalum and aluminium electrolytes in favour of ceramics whenever possible, because polarity only means trouble.

Comment: "finally a power transistor npn which will be connected to a 12V relay" Might want to add a freewheel diode then, unless that's included in the relay itself. Similarly, you might want some TVS on the input so you can pass EMC tests and sell the product legally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have said PCB designing is not your strong point, so let's give you some pointers:

Here are some general guidelines of PCB design in no specific order:

1. Know your mechanical constraints. These can be anything from board dimensions, connector position, height limitations, and mounting holes, yes, don't forget those, if unsure, always add 3mm holes 5mm from each edge at each corner.
2. Try to keep all polarised components facing the same direction. For example all the cathodes of the diodes pointing towards the top edge of the board. This makes assembly easier and reduces mistakes. The advice is valid for ICs as well. It makes the board aesthetically more pleasing. Please note that if the layout gets too complicated or puts the signal integrity at risk, then you can ignore this rule.
3. Avoid via holes as much as possible. Vias can be the weakpoint in a design, especially if you are etching the boards yourself. If you cannot avoid them, try to make them exposed so that they can be worked on if needed.
4. Make tracks as wide as you can, giving priority to the power supplies. As a general rule, calculate that a track 1mm wide can tollerate 2 Amps increasing in temperature by roughly 25 degrees Celsius. Keep that as a rule of thumb, but always exceed this for currents above 500mA. I don't know what the currents involved on your board are, but as a rough estimate I would suggest 1mm for the signal traces and 3mm for the powers. I know that they are oversized, but they are also much more forgiving.
5. Avoid passing tracks between the pins of an IC. Components can be moved, for example in your layout, just moving R7 and R8 between IC2 and IC3, will take away that nasty  track under IC3
6. Make the placement first, the routing later. If the ratsnet looks good, the layout will be easy. Spending time on carefully placing the components will save you a lot of time on the layout
7. Try to align the components so that they are spaced equally and aligned. If a board looks good, it is more likely to work. (it shows that you have taken the time required)
8. The tracks should be always routed at 90 degrees to each other, with only bends routed at 45 degrees. Intersections must be at 90 degrees, and make routes as short as possible, unless there is a good reason.
9. keep your clearances to other tracks, but most importantly to the pads. If a board like this, the minimum clearance should not be less than 1mm. IF you have the space, keeps as far as you can from pads.
10. If you intend to solder wires directly to the board, make sure that the holes are big enough for the wire to go through, and I recommend that you over size the pads, so that you have more mechanical strength. As a rule of thumb, these kind of pads, should be 3 times the diameter of the hole where the wire comes through.
11. Don't forget to tidy up the layout. Once you have finished the routing you are only half way there.

Spending 5 minutes in MS paint you can see how much more compact the board can be without pushing the boundaries. 
[image: Sample placement]

Don't forget to put some copper under the bodies of those TO220, so that they can dissipate a little bit more heat.

I will not go into the merits of your schematic, as you have already stated that the board works flawlessly.

Comment: Hi Elmesito, I am trying to follow your guidlines and I am at number 4. Does this look good so far? I updated the screenshot

Comment: Hi @M2T156 This is considerably better. Please ensure that you have set the design rules, so that clearances are maintained between tracks and pads. One more hint, is to move components only on a coarse grid, such as 2.54mm so that the components are more likely to fall in line with each other pretty much without any effort. You can neck down the trace power lines in proximity of the regulator the transistor. You can always beef that part at the end with teardrops or copper islands. The traces and placement around T2,T3 needs some attention.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Elmesito. I am using EAGLE and I do not really know how to do that. What do you mean by neck down the proximity lines? As in place the gnd - around that bend and put a 3mm line at the bottom?

Comment: Do I need to make the lines a bit thicker for T2 and T3 or is it something else?

Comment: What I mean by proximity is that when the traces connect to the pads of the regulator, you might need to reduce the width of the track in order to retain the clearance between the pads. The area around T2 and T3 can be improved by moving those components around. This will improve the layout of the traces. I don't use Eagle, so I cannot really help on how to use it, but Sparkfun have a tutorial on how to do it https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/115

Comment: I think I understand Elmesito. I will edit the lines and take a new screenshot when I am done. I will also read the page to further my understanding and progress in PCB design.

Comment: I have shrunker the traces on the regulator and trying to move those components. What do you think? It's hard to get my head around the components.

Comment: That is better. Don't worry about placing traces and then ripping them up, that is part of the design process. You try, and if it doesn't look as good as you expected, you remove the track, move a component a bit, and you draw and new track. repeat until you are satisfied.
I have played a bit with the traces. have a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOy7z.png

Comment: That's great, I understood what you did with the traces and I have tried to replicate them on EAGLE. I have attached a photo as to how it looks now. Now for the bottom components, should I add a GND - thick trace at the bottom and then connect everything up?

Comment: "Avoid via holes as much as possible" Eh? That might apply to some hobbyist project, but hardly to professional SMD boards with 4+ layers. There are many cases where you want _as many vias as possible_, for connecting ground planes etc.

Comment: The technical term you are looking for is stitching vias, but those don't apply to the design  OP is working on. Stitching vias have a purpose even in two layer boards. Anyhow, regardless of the quantity of layers, the amount of vias along a transmission line should be reduced to a minimum, in order to minimise the mismatch in impedance, avoid stubs on 4+ layer boards, and in general ensure a better signal integrity. Any rule has however an exception, but this is not the case.

Comment: What fuse would you put in for this one? https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0f46/0900766b80f46e63.pdf    I think 1.5 should be okay with all these components

Comment: I am not sure how much load you will have on the outputs, so it is hard to advise on a fuse. Said that, the voltage regulator has a maximum output of 1A, and presumably a short circuit protection, so the fuse will only help for what happens between the fuse and the regulator. If instead you intend to put the fuse before the transformer, and include the load to go through it, you should specify what this load is.